# Should I pass MyClass.__init__ constructor into factory method?

Tags: python, constructor, factory-pattern

I have a function which takes a factory method as an argument. Invoking the factory method will create an object. Now I thought that I could directly specify the constructor of the desired object/class `Fruit.__init__` as the factory method. But that does not work, since the `self` argument does "not exist" then. So I have to introduce an additional method `fruit_factory` which builds the object:

```
def fruit_factory(owner):
    return Fruit(owner)

class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, owner):
        print('Making a fruit for ' + owner)

def make_snack_for_jim(snack_factory):
    snack_factory('Jim')

make_snack_for_jim(fruit_factory) # Works, but needs additional function
make_snack_for_jim(Fruit.__init__) # Does not work (no 'self' argument)
```

Is there a way to directly specify the constructor instead of needing to create an additional method?

Comment: I don't really understand. Why can't you just load Fruit to the factory function?

Comment: As proposed in the answer by Markus Meskanen? Seems that I can do that, but I just did not think of it... ;-)

Comment: You need a return statement inside `def make_snack_for_jim(snack_factory): return snack_factory('Jim')` otherwise you don't return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass in the class itself:

```
>>> make_snack_for_jim(Fruit)
Making a fruit for Jim
```

This sets your `snack_factory` to `Fruit` inside of the `make_snack_for_jim`, which you then call with `snack_factory('Jim')`